# Unable to set mysql root password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

After installing mysql on Ubuntu (10.4), when I try to set the root password (sudo mysqladmin password NEW_PASSWORD) I get the following error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mysql database already has a root password. It was probably set when you installed mysql.

If you know the existing password, use this:

```
sudo mysqladmin -p password NEW_PASSWORD
```

The '-p' will tell mysql to prompt you to enter your old password first. Then, it will replace the existing password with the string NEW_PASSWORD.

If you do not remember the original password, you'll need to shut it down and start it following the instructions at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html . This is easy to do, but does require some downtime.

**UPDATE**

Another option.

You can tell Ubuntu to reconfigure your MySQL server. This will reconfigure mysql-server-5.1 from scratch, and will ask you for a new password from the root user. Caution: This will completely wipe out any existing data, and will replace them with the default data. However, I'm guessing your database doesn't contain anything.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1
```

(If I remember right, Ubuntu 10.04 comes with MySQL server 5.1, not 5.0)

Comment: I tried following those instructions, but I wasn't able to modify the table:


mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD('1492549') where user='root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1` to blow away and reconfigure your MySQL package, but this assumes you have nothing of value in the database. I updated my answer with this.

Answer (score 2):

To me, that error message suggests that there's already a root password set. It's been a while since I did a mysql install on Ubuntu, but I seem to remember the post-install dialogue asking me to specify a password at that point. Was this the case with your install?

If not, [this section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html) of the MySQL manual should be helpful.

Comment: I tried that, but I can't change the password (see comment above).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried the password of the first user. I could log in.

Typ in Terminal: mysql -u root -p

Enter password: [**password of the first user**]

If you use MySQL Administrator, you enter:

Server Hostname: **localhost**, Username: **root**, Password: [**password of the first user**]